# transmission-daemon web 403 forbidden

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, transmission

Using `transmission-daemon` on a Raspberry Pi with Respbian, I always get `403 Forbiden` when I try to visit `RPi_IP:9091/transmission/` from another computer via local network.

My settings.json:

```
"rpc-authentication-required": false, 
"rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0", 
"rpc-enabled": true, 
"rpc-password":"password",
"rpc-port": 9091, 
"rpc-url": "/transmission/", 
"rpc-username": "pi", 
"rpc-access-control-list":"127.0.0.1,*.*.*.*",
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,*.*.*.*", 
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,    /* not solved even I change this to true */
```

How to make the web UI work from non-localhost?

Answer (score 2):

It it possible, that the transsmision can't find its config file. In that case reads it from other place than `/etc/transsmision-daemon/`.
Try to run it in the foreground instead of daemonizing.

`transmission-daemon -f`

Then look from where transmission tries to read config file. It can be home directory of the user who runs transmission-daemon.

`(...)
[2016-08-13 16:18:00.906 UTC] Using settings from "/home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon"
(...)`

Stop transmission with `killall transmission-daemon`, then modify this file and run the daemon again.

Note: If it's the case of config file location, then you should check the `CONFIG_DIR` variable in `/etc/default/transmission-daemon`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the transmission-daemon by

> killall transmission-daemon

Then set "rpc-whitelist-enabled" to false

Run the daemon and voila, you can access the web UI.

Comment: `<sarsasm>`Everything works fine, when You disable security.`</sarcasm>`

Comment: Obviously a horrible permanent solution, but for debugging's sake, it lets the administrator determine if the RPC whitelist is the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

After torture ... :)
I found that in linux CentOS 7.5 there is other file with settings:

```
/var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

No matter what settings you make in

```
/root/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Transmission creates other `settings.json` file (with default settings) and eventually when you try to open the [Transmission webpage](http://your-local-ip/transmission) you get the Forbidden message.

Solution:

```
killall transmission-daemon
rm /var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
cp /root/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json /var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
chmod 0600 /var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

In this way we give only read permission for Transmission default settings.
Now lets start service:

```
systemctl start  transmission-daemon.service
systemctl enable transmission-daemon.service
```

I tested it as root user, but it is possible to run this service as any user you want.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of newer readers, I've also discovered another way I didn't see to bork this:
There's TWO whitelist fields in settings.json.  Hopefully that saves you some time.